# How to resolve "intel_agp module not found" error while trying to install a custom kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

I am running Fedora 17 in virtual-box. I am trying to do some kernel development. So, I got the source from **kernel.org** and then did the following steps:

```
make oldconfig
make
sudo make modules_install
```

This got me the `bzImage` file that I copied to `/boot`. Then I ran `grub2-mkconfig` which updated my grub entry.

Now I can see my custom kernel at the grub menu. However, when I try to run it, I get the following screen:

[image]

I searched for the `intel_agp` error and found that people got this error when they had both the `GPU` and `intel graphics` on their system. However I do not have a `GPU` on my machine. Also, I am not sure if the module is installed?

Am I doing something wrong here? How do I resolve this error?

Comment: First thing to do is probably figure out whether you do have the intel_agp driver and if it's built-in or the module is included in the initrd.

Comment: The `intel_agp` error is mostly harmless, particularly on a virtual system. The real problem is that your kernel didn't detect your virtual hard disk, and that's what's causing the failure.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is not the missing intel_agp module.  Your problem is the next line, which says that you can't mount your root file system.  The most likely reason is that you are missing an initramfs, which contains a driver for your root block device or filesystem.

I'm not really an expert on Fedora, but you probably need something like `mkinitrd` to produce an initramfs, which also needs to go in /boot and be included in your grub config for the new module you're building.

Or you can update your kernel config to build-in (ie set the config options to 'y' instead of 'm') everything that you need to build.  But that takes quite a bit of knowledge about your system and what Linux drivers it needs.

Answer (score 0):

Your distro looked like a Ubuntu, correct?   If so, then the command to make initrd is:

(assuming your current directory is the same as that containing your kernel source code)

```
update-initramfs -c -k `cat include/config/kernel.release`
```

and followed by:

```
update-grub
```

The logic of initrd and rootfs (roughly) goes like this:

First do a blkid and df:

```
blkid
/dev/sda5: UUID="251ce906-e4db-4eac-a2c7-58d5e1ed86a3" TYPE="reiserfs" 

df
Filesystem           1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda5             24412432  22360832   2051600  92% /
none                   2959228      2352   2956876   1% /dev
```

and u will see that the rootfs is on the reiserfs, where /boot lies.   So this means that reiserfs kernel module must be there when kernel loads up, otherwise it cannot read /boot, where vmlinuz kernel image likes.   So initrd is for this purpose.

The use of initrd (u can always do a gunzip -c existing_initrd_file | cpio -idmv) to unpack the contents and look at all the fs.*ko file.   Mine is:

```
./lib/modules/2.6.32-33-generic/kernel/fs/reiserfs/reiserfs.ko
./lib/modules/2.6.32-33-generic/kernel/fs/nfs_common/nfs_acl.ko
```

And then u try matching that with the config file:

```
CONFIG_REISERFS_FS=m
```

But if u have done the CONFIG_REISERFS_FS=y, then u will not need reiserfs.ko inside the initrd.

In summary, your problem right now is either a missing initrd file, or if the initrd file is specified in the commandline, then the necessary fs kernel module is missing in the initrd which will enable you to read the /boot directory.

Yes, this is not entirely correct too, when grub2 is involved - /boot/grub will contain its own fs kernel module to load /boot directory, and grub.cfg will have the necessary insert reiserfs statement to load the module.   Sorry, too much details to describe.

Comment: No the virtual machine is running Fedora. I don't know why I did that :P. I think I will change to Ubuntu. On Fedora, `update-grub2` script is not available. So, I updated the grub entry using `grub2-mkconfig`. It seems to work but I have not yet compared the source for the two. I will use the `update-initrafms` and post the results.